# angular fade animation with css3 transtions

Tags: angularjs, animation, css-transitions

I'm trying to fade in/out a div on click of a link using ngAnimate and css3 transitions. I have the following, but it isn't working. The div is shown/hidden, but does not fade in or out. Where did I go wrong:

```
.fade-in-out.ng-add {
  transition: 1s linear all;
  opacity: 0;
}

.fade-in-out.ng-add-active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.fade-in-out.ng-remove {
  transition: 1s linear all;
  opacity: 1;
}

.fade-in-out.ng-remove-active {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

The div is initially hidden (`showMe`=false). On the page is a link which sets `showMe` to true.

```
<div ng-show="showMe" class="fade-in-out">          
    <div style="float: right; cursor: pointer;" ng-click="showMe=false">x</div>
    blablabla
</div>
```

Note that I'm using angular 1.2.26.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The correct classes to use are:

```
.my-element.ng-hide-add, .my-element.ng-hide-remove {
  transition:0.5s linear all;
}

.my-element.ng-hide-add { ... }
.my-element.ng-hide-add.ng-hide-add-active { ... }
.my-element.ng-hide-remove { ... }
.my-element.ng-hide-remove.ng-hide-remove-active { ... }
```

In your case this will be enough:

```
.fade-in-out {
  transition: 1s linear all;  
  opacity: 1;
}

.fade-in-out.ng-hide {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/WM60wEYeQD7J1GuHG0WL?p=preview

*Note that `angular-animate.js` must be loaded and `ngAnimate` must be added as a dependant module.*

Comment: Just for understanding, why would ng-show not be the correct class to use?

Comment: Angular adds `ng-hide` when hiding something and removes it when showing something. Using the `ng-show` or `ng-hide` directive doesn't matter. There is no `ng-show` class that is added by Angular.

Comment: Since you're well versed in this area, can you take a look at a similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27140770/css-slide-animation-with-angularjs

Comment: Sure, will take a look :)

Comment: Thank you for your footer note, helped me avoid a giant headache!