# CSS slide animation with angularjs

Tags: css, angularjs, animation, transition, slide

I'm trying to animate a div using ng-show with CSS3 transitions. There are 2 divs: One in the foreground and another hidden behind it. The hidden div should slide up when the user mouse's over the foreground div. It should also remain shown if the users cursor moves over the slide div. If the users cursor leaves the slide div or the foreground div, it should slide back down. It doesn't seem to work correctly though. Here's a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/C1RaDTOXwpEMECGMkt19?p=preview

Is the css correct?

```
div#cover {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 90px;
  height: 30px;
  position:absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  z-index:10;
}


.slide {
  background-color: white;
  width: 90px;
  height: 30px;
  position:absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  z-index:5;
}

.slide.ng-hide-add, .slide.ng-hide-remove { 
    transition: bottom 1s ease;
}

.slide.ng-hide-remove-active {
    bottom: 30px
}

.slide.ng-hide-add-active {
    bottom: 0px
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need two states:

1. Shown
2. Hidden

Let the base `slide` class define the state for shown (30px from bottom):

```
.slide {
  background-color: white;
  width: 90px;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  z-index: 5;
  transition: 1s ease bottom !important;
  display: block !important;
}
```

When the expression used in the `ng-show` directive is evaluated to false the hidden state will be activated and the class `ng-hide` will be added to the element by Angular.

Use that class to decorate the base class and define the hidden state (0px from bottom):

```
.slide.ng-hide {
  bottom: 0;
}
```

This means the two states will have the following classes when active:

1. Shown: `slide`
2. Hidden: `slide ng-hide`

As you see the `slide` class is always present, which is why the `transition` is put there.

You must use `!important` on the `transition` otherwise if you move the cursor back and forth over the element Angular will override it with `transition: none` briefly, which will cause the transition to interrupt and the element to snap into its final position.

You must also use `display: block !important` in the `slide` class to override the default behavior of `ng-hide`, which is `display: none`.

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/WN8v2riSYhhMyOgbZiWO?p=preview

*Note: Personally I wouldn't recommend using `ng-mouseenter` or `ng-mouseleave` for this. Everytime they trigger the entire digest cycle and all watchers will be executed multiple times. The alternative would be to create a directive that uses event listeners to add/remove classes manually.*

Comment: Awesome, thanks for this! Just out of curiosity about final note, would changing the event to ng-mousedown just on the `cover` div prevent this problem?

Comment: You're welcome :) Yes, it should. The problem with `ng-mouseenter` and `ng-mouseleave` is that if you have a lot of them and a user moves the cursor across the screen, triggering multiple of them, you will have a bunch of unnecessary digest cycles. This can have a big impact on performance, especially on slower computers or mobile devices (unless your application is really thin of course). `ng-mousedown` is usually not triggered involuntarily as often.

Comment: I've used `$watch` here to register a watchExpression without a listener to `console.log` everytime one digest cycle runs: http://plnkr.co/edit/zn3L3mSy7asa6KtMi3yo?p=preview Try moving the cursor back and forth over the elements with the console opened and you will see how many of them are fired.